# Switching views with animation in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiview, transition

I'm trying to create a simple animation when switching from a view to another in iPhone.

I have a controller with its view. In the same xib file I placed another view I called viewTracks. I would like to write an action that switches from the default view of the controller to the view viewTracks. This is the code of the action I wrote in my controller:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:[self view] cache:YES];
UIView* sup = [[self view] superview];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[sup addSubview:viewTracks];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

All I see is that the view does switch, but without any animation. Is there any mistake here? Why do I see the correct switch of view without an the animation I specified?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend making the the two views you want to switch between be subviews of your view controller's view.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this? In Interface Builder I have those two views inside my xib file. How can I make them bubviews of my view controller's view? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Here's a screenshot of how your Interface Builder document window should look. Using the list view mode is very helpful for identifying where different views are sitting in the view hierarchy.

http://cl.ly/3PCA

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I still can't make it work... I created the new view and placed the others under it. The first is connected to the view member of my controller, and the others to two IBOutlet. I changed the code accordingly. Unfortunately I still can't see any transition and I can't even see the other view now.

Comment: Nevermind, been able to do it following our first advice. Just needed to think over this a little bit :-). Thanks!